# sforce.one is not working properly

Tags: visualforce, sforce

I am using below code to open one vf page in classic mode and another page in lightning mode. But every time it is opening classic page only. Why is there any error in my code. Please help me

```
    <apex:page >

<script type="text/javascript">

function isLightningExperienceOrSalesforce1(){
    return((typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one)); 
}  
function popupwindow(){

        if( isLightningExperienceOrSalesforce1() ) {
            window.open('/apex/customLightningLookup');
        } else {
            window.open('/apex/testVFpage'); 
        }
     }
</script>

<apex:form > 
    <apex:commandButton value="Generate Report" onclick="popupwindow(this);"/>
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is `customLightningLookup` a visualforce page, where you have used Lightning Out and accessed the lightning component. If `customLightningLookup` is a lightning component, as far as I know, you cannot open Lightning component using a url

Comment: Hi @Hemant customLightningLookup is a visualforce page, in that i used slds for look and feel of lightning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function inLightningExperience() {
    return 'Theme4d' === '{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed}';
}
function detectionOfTheme(){
    if(inLightningExperience()){
        alert('Success....you are in Lex'); 
    }else {
        alert('Success....you are in Classic'); 
    }
}
```

Its worked for me. Thank you @Tushar Sharma for you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This because in both case you are using `window.open` while you need to use `sforce` method to redirect.

```
if( isLightningExperienceOrSalesforce1() ) {
      sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/customLightningLookup');
} else {
      window.open('/apex/testVFpage'); 
}
```

[Navigation with the sforce.one Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm)

Comment: No it is not working @Tushar. Did you checked that. Every time below function returning false.............................................................. function isLightningExperienceOrSalesforce1(){
    return((typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one)); 
}

Comment: @ApexCode how did you open the current page. You are in LEX correct.

Comment: Yes @Tushar, when i am in Lightninig experience then also it is returning false...

Comment: @ApexCode how did you open the current page.

Comment: Clicking on Switch to Lightning experience. Setup ==> Then opening Visualforce page. I was checked 'available in Lightning' checkbox also.

Comment: Here The page is opened in Iframe so `sforce` won't work.  You might try `$User.UIThemeDisplayed` it will work for you.

Comment: @ApexCode I just checked your video and your page always open in classic. Can you try it with actual flow. Because in current case it is working as expected.